# I'm getting USBD_BUSY when i try to transmit sensor readings from sensor to my computer via virtual com port

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, stm32cubeide, nucleo, mpu6050

I'm trying to transmit MPU6050 sensor readings to my computer via virtual comport.I'm using STM32 Nucleo F446RE. As far as i can see in debug mode there is no issue in sensor and sensor readings. Problem is I can't transmit them using USB. Are there anyone who have experienced this issue before?

In the tutorial I watched the guy can transmit sensor reading with USB port and can see them with a serial port reader program. I'm sure that there is no issue in sensor the card sees sensor. I don't know why it keeps returning USBD_BUSY.

Transmit Code I'm using

[image: 1]

Comment: Post your code as text, not as an image. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/17208187)

Comment: You showing the part of the automatically generated code. BTW STM implementation is very poor. A lot of programming is required to make it good.

Comment: `char *data = "Hello World";

  while (1)
  {
  
 HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD2_GPIO_Port,LD2_Pin);
 HAL_Delay(1000);
 CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)data,strlen(data));

  }` This is the test code i use. Just a simple string. @0___________